# how to fetch date ("Y.m.d") from dat file

Tags: php, date, datetime

I want to fetch my date in ("Y.m.d") format

.dat file contains the following data, here

```
 3rd column is date 
177|RC456456177|1314160971|129$

178|RC456456456|1314167971|177$

179|RC456456456|1314130971|157$

180|RC456456456|1314260971|147$
```

I am using this to fetch the value

```
if($_POST['ordernum']==="")
{

$blank="Blank text box detected";
} 

elseif (isset($_POST["ordernum"]))
{

    $file = 'order.dat';

    $searchfor = $_POST["ordernum"];

$contents = file_get_contents($file);
// escape special characters in the query
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor,'/');

$pattern = "/^$pattern.*$/m";

if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
   $result = implode("", $matches[0]);

          $results = explode("|", $result);
          $settings->tid = $results[1];
          //echo $settings->tid;
        }
       else{
           $res="No result found";
          // echo  $res;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to read the file, or how to format the date? These are really two separate questions. (For the date, once it is read, you can simply call `date('Y.m.d', $date)`)

Comment: @Michael Mior :) question edited, i want to read in this format, right now my page show result like that 177|RC456456177|1314160971|129$

Comment: `$date = date('Y.m.d', $results[2])`?

Comment: No problem. Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code you posted above, this should do the trick.

```
$date = date('Y.m.d', $results[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

    $file = fopen ("whatever.dat", "r");

    while ($line = fgets($file)) {
        $contents = explode('|', $line);
        print date('Y.m.d', $contents[2]).PHP_EOL;
    }

    fclose ($file);
?>
```

That should work. HTH

Comment: `$contents[3]` or `$contents[2]`?

Answer (score 1):

```
// iterate through the file manually, it actually will be faster than reading
// it into either a long string or an array.
$fl = fopen( $path, 'r' );
$searchfor = $_POST["ordernum"] . '$';
// explode will not be needed because of fgetcsv
// http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php
while( $line = fgetcsv( $fl, 0, '|' ) )
{
    // test the last value
    if( $line[3] == $searchfor ) 
    {
        $settings->tid = date( 'Y-m-d', $results[2]);
        break;
    }
}
```

As a note (this won't work for my example), you should generally escape all `$` inside of double-quoted strings in PHP as a best practice.